# Change structure data to write to JSON

Tags: r, json, brackets, dataformat

Hi I would like to change the structure of data which I write to JSON but Im not sure how.

this is my code:

```
test_df <- data.frame(Metric = c("test1",
                                 "test2",
                                 "test3",
                                 "test4",
                                 "test5"),
                      Value = c(tail(test1$v, 1), 
                                tail(test2$v, 1),
                                tail(test3$v, 1),
                                tail(test4$v, 1),
                                tail(test5$v, 1)))
                                              


test_df_list <- list(test_df)

names(test_df_list) <- "test_df_df"

test_df_exportJSON <- toJSON(test_df_list, pretty = TRUE)

write(test_df_exportJSON, "test_df.json")
```

With result:

```
{
  "test_df": [
    {
      "Metric": "test1",
      "Value": 47
    },
    {
      "Metric": "test2",
      "Value": 0.85
    },
    {
      "Metric": "test3",
      "Value": 0.98
    },
    {
      "Metric": "test4",
      "Value": 137
    },
    {
      "Metric": "test5",
      "Value": 2.1
    }
  ]
}
```

But I would like to have the [] deleted like:

```
{
  "test_df": 
    {
      "test1": 47,
      "test2": 0.85,
       "test3": 0.98,
       "test4": 137,
       "test5": 2.1
    }
}
```

Any idea how to do this? Any help would e great!

Somehow I get the message "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" so ignore this line to have it accepted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `Metric` when creating the list and add it as names to the list elements later. Also split `Value` into single list items. Since I don't have your `test1` data at hand I created an example below.

```
library(jsonlite)
test_df <- data.frame(Metric = c('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'),
                      Value = c(4,6,2,8,7))

names <- as.vector(test_df$Metric)

test_df_list <- structure(split(test_df$Value, seq(nrow(test_df))), names = names)

test_df_list <- list(test_df = test_df_list)

toJSON(test_df_list, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Will give

```
{
  "test_df": {
    "test1": 4,
    "test2": 6,
    "test3": 2,
    "test4": 8,
    "test5": 7
  }
}
```

If you `remove auto_unbox = TRUE` from `toJSON()` the values will be in square brackets [
].
That's what worked for me but maybe somebody comes up with a more convenient solution.

Comment: Yes! Works! Thx!

Comment: @H.berg Good to know this worked! How `jsonlite` or other packages are converting will always depend on the structure of your data frame or list. Sometimes tricky to find the right structure though.